# Extract latest value from each row in a column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a DAX calculated column that only shows the new value added in the row. My data is collected in where for each new entry a new row is created where an entry is appended either at the start of the string or at the end. This history column may have a new value or could have a different column in the data set changed. The data looks like the following -

```
History row
A
A, B
A, B
C, A, B
D, C, A, B

Desired output is -

A
B
B
C
D
```

My goal is to extract only the new value or if no new value is added then the last value.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? There's no way to create a "DAX function". DAX is only available for defining measures, calculated columns/tables, and submitting queries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected the typo, I was hoping to have a "calculated column" created using DAX, not in the query view.

Comment: Please mark your previous questions as solved.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, there are things we need to keep in memory while processing each row:

- What was the value of the previous row?
- What was the character added last time?

For example, when we are looking at the 3rd row ("A,B"), we need additional information that *"the previous value was "A,B""*, and *""B" was the newest value added so far"* to figure out the answer ("B"). In other words, we need to retain some "state" during the iteration.

However, unfortunatelly, DAX does not have any function which allows stateful iteration. So I don't think this is possible with DAX.

I would do this with Power Query. Some kind of Power Query functions, such as `List.Accumulate`, support stateful iteration.

So here is an example.

```
let
    #"History Values" = {
        "A",
        "A,B",
        "A,B",
        "C,A,B",
        "D,C,A,B"
    },
    
    #"New Values" =
    List.Accumulate(
        #"History Values",
        [Last = null, LastAdded = null, History = {}],
        (state as record, current as text) as record =>
            let
                newValue =
                    if state[Last] = null then current
                    else if state[Last] = current then state[LastAdded]
                    else if Text.StartsWith(current, state[Last]) then Text.End(current, 1)
                    else if Text.EndsWith(current, state[Last]) then Text.Start(current, 1)
                    else error "unexpected"
            in
                [Last = current, LastAdded = newValue, History = state[History] & {newValue}]
    )[History]

in
    Table.FromColumns(
        {#"History Values", #"New Values"},
        type table [History = text, New Values = text]
    )
```

[image: result image in Power Query]